# List[EitherT[Future, A, B]] to EitherT[Future, A, List[B]] with cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I'm not able to transform a list of EitherT to a EitherT of list using cats 1.0.1:

```
import cats.implicits._

val list: List[EitherT[Future, String, Int]] = List(1.pure, 2.pure)
val eitherOfList : EitherT[Future, String, List[Int]] = list.sequence
```

The error is: the expression of type Nothing[List[Nothing]] doesn't conform to expected type EitherT[Future, String, List[Int]]

Comment: Could you provide the import you are using please ?

Comment: just add it in the example

Answer (score 3):

Sadly scala type inference isn't that great, so you'll have to annotate your code, when using the `pure` syntax.

```
type Stack[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

val list: List[Stack[Int]] = List(1.pure[Stack], 2.pure[Stack])
val eitherOfList: Stack[List[Int]] = list.sequence
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I still having the compilation issue, not sure if it can because of some missing imports from cats

Comment: @MaxenceCramet in order for the second line to work, you need to enable the `-Ypartial-unification` flag of the compiler (it's available on scala 2.11.9+ or via this plugin https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification)

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, but it's already in my build.sbt. For info I'm using sbt 1.1.0 and scala 2.12.4